# Create WordPress User With MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Trying to create a new WordPress user directly through MySQL by running a query. I keep seeing an error message popup :

1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'user_registered' at row 1

How can include what is missing?

```
INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_status`)
VALUES ('adminuser2', MD5('adminuser2password'), 'adminfirstname adminlastname', 'adminuser2@mywebsite.com', '0');

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
VALUES (NULL, (Select max(id) FROM wp_users), 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
VALUES (NULL, (Select max(id) FROM wp_users), 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this syntax, it's the recommended way to insert data while you're using WordPress

```
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array('column_name_1'=>'hello', 'other'=> 123), array( '%s', '%d' ) );
```

define a variable: 
`$blogtime = current_time( 'mysql' );` then add 'user_registered' column to your query

```
$wpdb->insert( 'wp_users' , array(
    'user_login' => 'adminuser2',
    'user_pass'  => MD5('adminuser2password'),
    'user_nicename'=> 'adminfirstname adminlastname',
    'user_email'=> 'adminuser2@mywebsite.com',
    'user_status'=> '0',
    'user_registered'=> '$blogtime' 
));
```